# Webscraping python promotion information

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new working with python and trying to scrape a website using beautifulsoup.
I can get information like the title and price but I can't get the promotion-information

Website: https://www.vitaminstore.nl/product/vitacura-vitamine-c-500-mg-calcium-ascorbaat-tabletten-1306065

Information needed: "Vitacura Vitamine C 1+1 gratis"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoVHa.png)

```
import:
import requests
from glob import glob
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

HEADERS = ({'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})



Promotion = soup.find("div", { "class" : "o-Promotions__Info" }).findall('span', { "class" : "o-Promotions__Title" })
```

Could anyone help me fix this?

Many thanx!!

Answer (score 1):

The *selenium* module is ideal for processing web pages that are reliant on Javascript. You can achieve your objective like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
CLASS = 'o-Promotions__Title'

with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:
    driver.get('https://www.vitaminstore.nl/product/vitacura-vitamine-c-500-mg-calcium-ascorbaat-tabletten-1306065')
    # wait up to 5 seconds for the relevant class to be observable
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, CLASS)))
    span = BS(driver.page_source, 'lxml').select_one(f'span.{CLASS}')
    print(span.text.strip())
```

**Output:**

```
Vitacura Vitamine C 1+1 gratis
```

**Note:**

You will need to install chromedriver for this. Details on selenium website

Answer (score 0):

You don't need selenium when you can fetch the data directly. Just feed the product id into the url.

```
import requests

productId = '1306065'

url = f'https://www.vitaminstore.nl/Promotion/GetProductPromotion?productId={productId}'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36'}
jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

promotions = jsonData['RelatedPromotions']
for promotion in promotions:
    print(promotion['Name'])
```

**Output:**

```
Vitacura Vitamine C 1+1 gratis
```

Comment: How would you avoid using something like selenium when you are limited to using the URL as shown in the original question?

Comment: why/how are you limited to use that exact url?

Comment: And to answer your question, if you have that page urls, you extract the productId from it  and then use it to feed into the `GetProductPromotion`